# Synchronised method in PHP Thread called by 2 different users

Tags: php, multithreading, concurrency

This is more of a general question since I can't be specific with code snippets, so please if possible, answer in a general manner.

If i create a Thread extended class, and I define a synchronised method, when 2 visitors create a new instance of that class and calls the synchronised method, will it work or will it only work if it is called 2 times by the same user?

What I am trying to achieve is: each visitor, opens a thread so that a sequence of commands are ran in parallel with the normal script, but I don't want that sequence of commands to be ran by more visitors in the same time.

I know the question is not too specific, but I did not find any documentation to clearly explain this..

Note: I am coming from Java, so some terms may be wrong for PHP.

EDIT: ' Elaborate what you mean when you say "opens a thread so that a sequence of commands are ran in parallel with the normal script" and " I don't want that sequence of commands to be ran by more visitors in the same time." '.

- 2 Different Visitors access `script.php` at the same time.
- `script.php` has somewhere inside:

  - `$commands = new <class that extends Thread>();`
  - `$commands-><synchronised method>();`
- Visitor 2 waits until Visitor 1's `$commands-><synchronised method>();` terminates, and just then runs his `$commands-><synchronised method>();`.

This is the goal.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean when you say "opens a thread so that a sequence of commands are ran in parallel with the normal script" and " I don't want that sequence of commands to be ran by more visitors in the same time." Please also provide an example that illustrates what you mean.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `Threaded::synchronized` implements functionality similar to Java's `synchronized` and is described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/threaded.synchronized.php).

The problem you'll encounter in PHP is that you're trying to get two sessions to execute the same synchronized method on the *same object*, and vanilla PHP doesn't support sharing objects in-memory between sessions. You'll note that in your example script,

```
$commands = new <class that extends Thread>();
$commands-><synchronised method>();
```

A new object is being created *per script invocation*.

You could implement something like this by using an external resource to control access within your method, like a lockfile (probably the quickest and least elegant way). Depending on what else is in your software stack, you might be able to store the mutex in the database or other store you're using.